# store and retrieve array values in one MySQL column

Tags: php, mysql

can someone help me, i have table packs.

```
id    pid  price
1     10   25
2     20   50
3     30   100
```

but i don't want to store this value in database table, but in one single column i have seen many examples like this.

```
a:10:{s:5:"theme";i:19659555;s:7:"version";s:5
```

another example

```
[[0,50],[20,62],[48,92]]
```

I prefer and i think the first example is good, any idea how to store and receive it from database?

thanks in advance..

Comment: _"but i don't want to store this value in database table"_ - I guess you really mean that you don't want to store it in _separate columns_ in the database table? Either way, this question is too broad. You need to do some proper research and at least make some attempts yourself first. We're glad to help you sort out specific _issues_ you might have in your existing code, but we're not here to do your job for you.

Comment: yes, i don't want to create another table for this entries, but store them in one single column.

Comment: Why? It's generally better to have it normalized like the table you already have. If you store everything as a string in one column, you won't be able to search for records having specific values, index the table in a good way or do joins. Or it at least won't be efficient at all.

Comment: If you really want to do it, just do it. The first string is the result of [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and the other string just looks like [json](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Please make some attempts to solve this yourself first and come back in case you run into issues along the way. Read through [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well.

Comment: ok, i will make some attempt, btw before i move, do you think i can't do some search, for example if i want to verify "[10,25]" exists or not. can I do so?

Comment: You can, but it won't be as fast since the database won't be able to utilize indexes, which drastically improves the speed of your queries. In a relational database, each separate value should have it's own column with the correct data type and index (if needed). Then you can easily search for values and join tables on the values. Searching for integers is very fast in MySQL while searching for a partial string is not. If you have a relational database, you should use it properly.

Comment: Obviously, you're not obliged to use an RDBMS as part of your solution, but if you do want to use an RDBMS as part of you're solution then I see no advantage in not doing so properly.

Comment: Don't, just don't. It'll likely cause lots of trouble later. Just leave the schema normalized as it is. That's the safest bet.